# How can I write underset tag properly in the reaction?

Tags: mhchem, chemistry

I am using mhchem package for writing chemical reactions in my blog. How shall I use the underset tag properly so that the text hydrogen ion will come just below the product?

Code I have tried is below:

```
\ce{H – e^–>\underset{\text{Hydrogen ion}}{\ce{H^+}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have

- `–` instead of `-` (twice)
- missing spaces around the arrow (and a missing dash): `->`
- missing `$ ... $` around `underset{}{}`
- a missing `}` at the end.

Correcting all this gives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{H - e^- -> $\underset{\text{Hydrogen ion}}{\ce{H^+}}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]